# Detect Enter Key in Javascript with no Input fields

Tags: javascript

I am creating a custom notification popup, and I am trying to detect an Enter key in Javascript on a form that has no input fields.

I have tried adding "onkeypress" to my  tag but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If a form has no input field, it is not focusable: so you will need to bind the keypress event to the `window` object.

Comment: Adding the code that you wrote to the question will let us know for sure if it's the case that @Terry described.

Comment: This worked, but the problem is that I need to detect it only in the modal window that displays the custom notification.  The Modal Window is not using an iframe.

Comment: use onkeypress in the html tag.

Comment: I have tried all these suggestions, except adding it to the html tag which wouldn't work for a modal popup, and nothing is working yet.

Comment: One more thing...the page that triggers the modal popup has a form itself that contains a keypress event, so maybe I need to suppress the page keypress event when the modal window is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

e.which is 13 on enter and e.target tells you where that happened

e.code is "Enter" but is [less supported](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-code)

```js
window.addEventListener("keypress",function(e) { 
  console.log(e.target.tagName,e.which === 13) 
})
```

```html
<form>
<input type="button">
</form>
```

Only on the form

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("keypress",function(e) { 
  console.log(e.target.tagName,e.which === 13) 
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="button">
</form>
```

In a div:

```js
document.getElementById("popup").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.tagName, e.target.closest("div").id, e.which === 13)
})
```

```css
#popup {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document
  .querySelector("#my_form")
  .addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      console.log("hiii");
    }
  });
```

```html
<form id="my_form" style="border: 1px solid red; outline: 0" tabindex="0">
  <label>....</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Some explanation is good. I also made you a snippet - Please note that IE does not support `.code`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses.  I am quite sure, under normal circumstances, they would have worked.  However, since my modal (which needed to detect a keypress) was display over a form (which also had a keypress), I had to add a modal status (visible/hidden) and edit the keypress of my main form based on the modal status.

```
function handleKeyPress(e)
{
    var key=e.keyCode || e.which;

    var modalstatus = $("#modalstatus").val();

    if (key==13)
    {
        if (modalstatus == "hidden")
            Event_On_Main_Page();
        else
            Modal_Event();
    }
}
```